# Source install of GDAL 3.0.1 fails with undefined references to EVP_MD_CTX_new and EVP_MD_CTX_free

Tags: gdal

I am installing GDAL 3.0.1 from source on Ubuntu 16.04, with the following steps.

```
$ wget https://download.osgeo.org/gdal/3.0.1/gdal-3.0.1.tar.gz
$ tar xzf gdal-3.0.1.tar.gz
$ cd gdal-3.0.1

$ ./configure --with-python --with-png=internal --with-jpeg=internal
$ make
```

Running `./configure` goes without problems:

```
GDAL is now configured for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

  Installation directory:    /usr/local
  C compiler:                gcc -DHAVE_AVX_AT_COMPILE_TIME -DHAVE_SSSE3_AT_COMPILE_TIME -DHAVE_SSE_AT_COMPILE_TIME -g -O2
  C++ compiler:              g++ -std=c++11 -DHAVE_AVX_AT_COMPILE_TIME -DHAVE_SSSE3_AT_COMPILE_TIME -DHAVE_SSE_AT_COMPILE_TIME -g -O2
  C++14 support:             no

  LIBTOOL support:           yes

  LIBZ support:              external
  LIBLZMA support:           no
  ZSTD support:              no
  cryptopp support:          no
  crypto/openssl support:    yes
  GRASS support:             no
  CFITSIO support:           no
  PCRaster support:          internal
  LIBPNG support:            internal
  DDS support:               no
  GTA support:               no
  LIBTIFF support:           internal (BigTIFF=yes)
  LIBGEOTIFF support:        internal
  LIBJPEG support:           internal
  12 bit JPEG:               yes
  12 bit JPEG-in-TIFF:       yes
  LIBGIF support:            internal
  JPEG-Lossless/CharLS:      no
  OGDI support:              no
  HDF4 support:              no
  HDF5 support:              yes
  Kea support:               no
  NetCDF support:            yes
  NetCDF has netcdf_mem.h:   no
  Kakadu support:            no
  JasPer support:            no
  OpenJPEG support:          no
  ECW support:               no
  MrSID support:             no
  MrSID/MG4 Lidar support:   no
  JP2Lura support:           no
  MSG support:               no
  EPSILON support:           no
  WebP support:              no
  cURL support (wms/wcs/...):yes
  PostgreSQL support:        yes
  LERC support:              yes
  MySQL support:             no
  Ingres support:            no
  Xerces-C support:          no
  Expat support:             yes
  libxml2 support:           yes
  Google libkml support:     no
  ODBC support:              no
  FGDB support:              no
  MDB support:               no
  PCIDSK support:            internal
  OCI support:               no
  GEORASTER support:         no
  SDE support:               no
  Rasdaman support:          no
  DODS support:              no
  SQLite support:            yes
  PCRE support:              yes
  SpatiaLite support:        no
  RasterLite2 support:       no
  Teigha (DWG and DGNv8):    no
  INFORMIX DataBlade support:no
  GEOS support:              yes
  SFCGAL support:            no
  QHull support:             internal
  Poppler support:           no
  Podofo support:            no
  PDFium support:            no
  OpenCL support:            no
  Armadillo support:         no
  FreeXL support:            no
  SOSI support:              no
  MongoDB support:           no
  MongoCXX v3 support:       no
  HDFS support:              no
  TileDB support:            no
  userfaultfd support:       yes
  misc. gdal formats:        aaigrid adrg aigrid airsar arg blx bmp bsb cals ceos ceos2 coasp cosar ctg dimap dted e00grid elas envisat ers fit gff gsg gxf hf2 idrisi ignfheightasciigrid ilwis ingr iris iso8211 jaxapalsar jdem kmlsuperoverlay l1b leveller map mrf msgn ngsgeoid nitf northwood pds prf r raw rmf rs2 safe saga sdts sentinel2 sgi sigdem srtmhgt terragen til tsx usgsdem xpm xyz zmap rik ozi grib eeda plmosaic rda wcs wms wmts daas rasterlite mbtiles pdf
  disabled gdal formats:    
  misc. ogr formats:         aeronavfaa arcgen avc bna cad csv dgn dxf edigeo geoconcept georss gml gmt gpsbabel gpx gtm htf jml mvt ntf openair openfilegdb pgdump rec s57 segukooa segy selafin shape sua svg sxf tiger vdv wasp xplane idrisi pds sdts ods xlsx amigocloud carto cloudant couchdb csw elastic gft ngw plscenes wfs gpkg vfk osm
  disabled ogr formats:     


  SWIG Bindings:             python 

  PROJ >= 6:                 yes
  enable GNM building:       yes
  enable pthread support:    yes
  enable POSIX iconv support:yes
  hide internal symbols:     no
```

However, when running `make`, it exits with the following error:

```
... /.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
... /.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
GNUmakefile:82: recipe for target 'gdalinfo' failed
make[1]: *** [gdalinfo] Error 1
```

What I've seen when searching for this error is that it relates to OpenSSL.

I have several versions of OpenSSL installed, and I am afraid that that is where it might get messed up.

The OpenSSL installed with apt-get is:

```
$ /usr/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

However, there is also an OpenSSL installed with Miniconda (which comes before usr/bin in the search path)

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
```

I don't know how to tell GDAL where to find OpenSSL, and if that would actually solve my problem either way.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I know this is old but wondering if the OP resolved this issue?

Comment: @ShawnW In the end I just gave up and used an older GDAL version via ubuntugis ;) Maybe I should try again and see if magic happened

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "gdal" is but I saw your question and wanted to leave the hint, that, while compiling, libraries are needed instead of the binary.

In your special case the OpenSSL Crypto Lib is needed. And as you found out correctly the functions EVP_MD_CTX_new and EVP_MD_CTX_free were introduced in version 1.1.

So I assume you have not installed the correct libraries.

You can search for the term libcrypto.so to look up your version. Most times this is a symlink that points to the real lib with the version in it. (libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.1)
On my machine (ubuntu) the lib is located in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.

Hope that helps.